# Track keywords and rankings using the Google Custom Seach API

Tags: seo, keywords, api, google-programmable-search-engine

Is it possible to use Google Custom Seach API to allow me to track keywords for our website as well as some of our clients?

There are mixed views from what I can tell and read. I'm going to be buying the API which allows me to have around 10k requests per year, so I won't be using the free version.

Also, in terms of optimization - Is it possible to not favour my domain over everyone elses? It appears that when the results from the API come back, my domain seems to be at number 1 whereas if I do a search on my browser, the result is actually number 5 in the list for that specific keyword.

Comment: I don't know about the API, but you can see the keywords in Google Analytics using this method:  [Connecting Google Analytics with Custom Search Engine AdSense](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52864/connecting-google-analytics-with-custom-search-engine-adsense)

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller  - I maybe wrong but this would not be suitable. I need to use this for clients, there may not have this set up nor want to give me their details.. If that makes sense? It would require me authenticating them, and accessing their webmaster tools

Comment: Webmaster Tools has nothing to do with it.   Only Google Analytics.  You could set it up so they could see their own keywords in Google Analytics without ever logging into to GA as them, just by changing their site.    If you want to see your clients keywords, then you would need access to their analytics.  Using that method, the keywords would also appear in the access log, so you could see them if you had access to that.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Oh, okay! Will this give me their keyword ranking, though? I.e. If they have a keyword "seo" will it track the position say "today: position 1", "yesterday: position 3" etc..

Comment: No, it only tells you what was searched.   But with a custom search engine you typically have only your site in the results anyway, right?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller - No, from what I can see, they have other results also... The only issue is that the custom search will favour my url over anyone elses. Which, is not ideal..